# Replace pointer to pointer by initializer_list

Tags: c++11

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//this api is anti intuition
void original(int const **data)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i){
        int const *ptr = *data;
        //std::cout<<*ptr++<<", "<<*ptr<<std::endl; //this line may cause undefined behavior
        std::cout<<ptr[0]<<", "<<ptr[1]<<std::endl;
        ++data;
    }
}

//my eyes prefer this api than original like api
void replace_original(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> list)
{
    std::vector<int const*> results(list.size());        

    for(auto data : list){        
        results.push_back(std::begin(data)); //#1
    }

    original(&results[0]);
}

int main()
{         
    int first[] = {0, 1};
    int second[] = {2, 3};
    int third[] = {4, 5};

    int const *array[] = {first, second, third};
    original(array);
    replace_original({ {0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5} });

    return 0;
}
```

The results are

```
0, 1
2, 3
4, 5
```

expected results are

```
0, 1
2, 3
4, 5
0, 1
2, 3
4, 5
```

I want to encapsulate the api of original(old, c style api) by the api like replace_original
But can't figure out why #1 can't work.

Comment: `std::cout<<*ptr++<<", "<<*ptr<<std::endl;` This line is undefined. You modify `ptr` and access it in a different part of the expression.

Comment: @Sebastian Redl What do you mean undefined behavior?I change the address of ptr but do not change the contents of the ptr point to.

Comment: @StereoMatching: You access the address twice in that row (`*ptr++` and `*ptr`) while modifying it during the `*ptr++`. This is undefined behavior, since C++ doesn't make any guarantees about the order of the two accesses to `ptr`.

Comment: @Grizzly do you mean I should not access the ptr in the same row but separate it to different row?Or just access it by ptr[0], ptr[1]?

Comment: Either would work. If you split your output into two statements you get a clearly defined sequencing between the two expressions involving `ptr`, thus solving your problem. If you access as `ptr[0]` and `ptr[1]` you don't modify `ptr`, meaning that the order in which the statements are evaluated doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, stupid mistake, I should change the loop to

```
    size_t const size = list.size();
    std::vector<int const*> results(size);
    for(size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i){
        results[i] = std::begin( *(std::begin(list) + i) );
    }
```

Do you have a better solution to encapsulate this kind of api?
After google, I find out that in c++14, size() of initializer_list will
become constexpr so we should be able to use std::array to replace std::vector

Comment: No, `size()` may be constexpr, but that only applies to a context where the `initializer_list` itself is a compile-time constant, which it isn't inside `replace_original`.

Comment: What kind of situation the size() would become a compile time constant?May you show me some examples?Thanks

Comment: `constexpr std::initializer_list<int> il = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; static_assert(5 == il.size(), "here");`